# Is it possible to do Record wise encryption for DB's using AWS KMS

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

i am looking is it possible to do  Record wise encryption for DB's using AWS KMS.I know that entire DB can encrypt using AWS KMS but i want to know if there is any possibility to do a Individual Record Wise Encryption using AWS KMS.I was searching this on google but haven't got any information

Comment: The only option I see is if you will encrypt records/fields on the application level.

Comment: yes , according to my research it should be done in application layer